# retain assigned values from within block in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to create an app that implements customized tunnel protocols.
and having issue with assigning value to variable from block, see following code

```
@implementation ProfileTableViewController{
     __block NSArray *vpnProfiles;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
[NETunnelProviderManager loadAllFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* newManagers, NSError *error)
     {
         if(error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Load Preferences error: %@", error);
         }else{

             if([newManagers count] > 0)
             {
                 vpnProfiles = newManagers;
                 NSLog(@"vpnProfiles 1st: %ld", [vpnProfiles count]);
             }
         }
     }];

 NSLog(@"vpnProfiles 2nd: %ld", [vpnProfiles count]);
}
```

the above will print

```
vpnProfiles 2nd: 0
vpnProfiles 1st: 1
```

my understanding is that this issue is due to async threads, but i can't seem to find a solution after searching and trying.

anyone has suggestions on how to get ***newManagers*** to local variable ***vpnProfiles***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is a misunderstanding in the code about the purpose of the `__block` qualifier.

This qualifier only applies to local variables (see [*The `__block` Storage Qualifier*](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#the-block-storage-qualifier) in the *Language Specification for Blocks*) as its purpose is to extend the lifetime of local variables, if they are modifiable by blocks, past their usual demise once the method/function/language-block they are defined in exits.

In the code `vpnProfiles` is an *instance variable*, whose lifetime is tied to the lifetime of its owning object instance, and as such `__block` has no meaning – unfortunately the compiler doesn't warn you but just ignores it. Instance variables can be captured and modified by a block as doing so captures the owning object instance as well, thus usually(†) keeping it alive as it is referenced by the block.

And now to the main question and remark:

> my understanding is that this issue is due to async threads

Exactly.

Your `loadAllFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:` method accepts a completion handler which it will presumably run at some future time *after* the method it has returned...

Therefore the `NSLog` within the block is executed *after* the `NSLog` following the call to `loadAllFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:` – as can be seen by the output shown in the question.

> anyone has suggestions on how to get `newManagers` to <s>local</s> *instance* variable `vpnProfiles`?

It is already being assigned by the statement `vpnProfiles = newManagers;` – the problem is that the code is checking for the assignment *before* it has happened.

> but i can't seem to find a solution

The clue is in the name of your method, the block is a *completion handler* which will be called at some future time when the `newManagers` are available. It is *within* this completion handler that you need to schedule the work to do *after* that point.

So, for example, you might do the assignment to `vpnProfiles` and then use `dispatch_async()` to schedule a block which calls a method on your `ProfileTableViewController` instance which reads `vpnProfiles` and does whatever is needed.

> I'm trying to create an app that implements customized tunnel protocols.

It is time to further research asynchronous design methods as it is essential for such code. Have fun!

HTH

*Note*

(†) If the captured object reference is *weak* the object is not kept alive. To find out more about this research "reference cycles" and "weak self".